# Electrum server full node bitcoin core wallet- how to block all outside access?

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, full-node, server

i have read that with an EPS electrum server, other nodes in the network  can "ping" your port , i believe the port no. was 8333. How can I for sure and for any situation block such accesses? The EPS should be isolated, only interact with my full node and should not participate in any other communication within the network.

Can you please guide me through the steps which settings I should change, and where?

Thanks

Comment: Port 8333 is exposed by the full node, not by EPS. It's the port Bitcoin nodes use to communicate with each other. You can disable incoming connections on your node if you don't like that (set listen=0 in bitcoin.conf).

Comment: thx! this is it, is there any other parameter except this port 8333 which I could edit, related to network interactions?  And is your hint with the bitcoin.conf file related to a Windows machine? If not could you also give the way to change on Windows? thx